# Why won't lines from GPX simplify/generalize/smooth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, gpx, simplify

I am working with GPX data. I imported them to ArcGIS by 'GPX to feature' and then I created lines from these points. I am trying to smooth (or simplify) the lines now, but the tools 'smooth line' and 'simplify line' are not working. (Maybe it is because of the large number of points)

Do you know any tools or hints how to smooth these lines created from GPX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As emerged from the comments the troubleshooting steps which led to resolving this were:

> Were the Generalize and Smooth tools from the Advanced Editing toolbar
> being used?

They were.

> How many vertices did the line which was failing to smooth/generalise
> have?

The [Count Vertices](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=41be32b271904f82bc547a57548f55c2) tool was downloaded to do the count and then it became evident that the "line" was actually many single segment lines that had been created from a 'split line on vertices tool".  Lines with only two vertices cannot be smoothed/generalized further.